# JPA Inheritance attributes from non entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I saw many posts around this problem however many of the answers that I found was to use the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation which in my case destroys the modular design that I made.

Imagine that you have two class, one is a Entity class and the other is in another module that is not a Entity class:

Module M:

```
@Entity
public class A {
 //Properties
}
```

Module M':

```
public class SuperA {
   String name;
   String age;

   //getters and setters
}
```

I want to re-use the properties of **SuperA** to be mapped in the **A** entity. But I don't want to let the Module M' neither the class **SuperA** about the persistence knowledge(e.g. Avoiding @MappedSuperclass annotation).

How should I approx this? I thought in a Adapter pattern for the **A** class, but I am not sure...

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options:

**1)** You have to add an XML based Hibernate config as part of your entire Persistence Unit. Having in mind avoiding any additional change in module M:

```
<component name = "SuperA">
        // properties
</component>
```

Here you would register the SuperA class as an embeddable.

**2)** Extend `SuperA` in the first module and mark that class as `@Embeddable`. Then in each entity that needs it just create a field and annotate it with `@Embedded`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realize that by trying to extend the SuperA class and try to avoid the knowledge of the persistence layer in the Module M' I will find another problem with consistence in the module M. If something change in SuperA I will be obligated to change A class.